# Browser automation at Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

I need to do a **browser automation** (eg. thru Puppeteer, Selenium) for the purpose of web scraping [to fetch dynamic content from web]. A client wants **script to be hosted and run at the GAS**.

Basically GAS allows Node.js scripting in it. Yet, I can't find any docs/info on possibility of launching browser instances/incl. headless mode.

Any hints ? Any walkarounds to fetch dynamic content from GAS ?

Comment: Probably no one has accomplished it so far.